# Representing SQL constraints on a table

Tags: mysql

I have this table:

```
CREATE  TABLE `sold` (
`part_ID` INT(11) NOT NULL ,
`date` DATE NOT NULL ,
 PRIMARY KEY (`part_ID`, `date`) ,
 FOREIGN KEY (`part_ID` )
 REFERENCES `part` (`part_ID` );
```

This table represent parts sold each day, constraint says number of sales should be at least 25 and at most 100.

I think it should start with something like this:

```
CHECK ( NOT EXISTS ...
```

Comment: Question: You put the tag `sql`. Do you really means `sql-server` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, to tell you: Check Constraints are not implemented in MySQL.

You are probably better off writing a `BEFORE INSERT`,`BEFORE UPDATE` trigger that would check the count using something like

```
SELECT COUNT(1) into UnitSold
FROM sold WHERE partId = OLD.partId
```

## SCENARIO : Implement a check constraint by means of a trigger

We have a simple `sold` table that look like this:

```
use test
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `sold`;
CREATE  TABLE `sold` (
`part_ID` INT(11) NOT NULL ,
`date` DATE NOT NULL ,
`name` VARCHAR(20),
 PRIMARY KEY (`part_ID`, `date`)
);
```

Let create it:

```
mysql> use test
Database changed
mysql> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `sold`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> CREATE  TABLE `sold` (
    -> `part_ID` INT(11) NOT NULL ,
    -> `date` DATE NOT NULL ,
    -> `name` VARCHAR(20),
    ->  PRIMARY KEY (`part_ID`, `date`)
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.06 sec)

mysql>
```

Here is the trigger to only allow 3 sales per part_ID

```
DELIMITER $$   
CREATE TRIGGER sold_beforeinsert_trigger
BEFORE INSERT ON sold FOR EACH ROW   
BEGIN   
    DECLARE UnitsSold INT;

    SELECT COUNT(1) INTO UnitsSold FROM sold WHERE part_ID = NEW.part_ID;
    IF UnitsSold >= 3 THEN
        SELECT COUNT(gummybears) INTO UnitsSold
        FROM information_schema.schemata;
    END IF;

END; $$ 
DELIMITER ;
```

Let's create it:

```
mysql> DELIMITER $$
mysql> CREATE TRIGGER sold_beforeinsert_trigger
    -> BEFORE INSERT ON sold FOR EACH ROW
    -> BEGIN
    ->     DECLARE UnitsSold INT;
    ->
    ->     SELECT COUNT(1) INTO UnitsSold FROM sold WHERE part_ID = NEW.part_ID;
    ->     IF UnitsSold >= 3 THEN
    ->         SELECT COUNT(gummybears) INTO UnitsSold
    ->         FROM information_schema.schemata;
    ->     END IF;
    ->
    -> END; $$
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.08 sec)

mysql> DELIMITER ;
mysql>
```

Here is some sample data to load and display:

```
SET @DaysBack = 0;
SET @DaysBack = @DaysBack + 1; SET @GivenDate = DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL @DaysBack DAY);
INSERT INTO `sold` VALUES ( 1, DATE(@GivenDate), 'rolando');
INSERT INTO `sold` VALUES ( 2, DATE(@GivenDate), 'pamela');
INSERT INTO `sold` VALUES ( 3, DATE(@GivenDate), 'dominique');
INSERT INTO `sold` VALUES ( 4, DATE(@GivenDate), 'diamond');
SELECT * FROM sold;
```

Let's run this:

```
mysql> SET @DaysBack = 0;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SET @DaysBack = @DaysBack + 1; SET @GivenDate = DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL @DaysBack DAY);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO `sold` VALUES ( 1, DATE(@GivenDate), 'rolando');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO `sold` VALUES ( 2, DATE(@GivenDate), 'pamela');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO `sold` VALUES ( 3, DATE(@GivenDate), 'dominique');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO `sold` VALUES ( 4, DATE(@GivenDate), 'diamond');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM sold;
+---------+------------+-----------+
| part_ID | date       | name      |
+---------+------------+-----------+
|       1 | 2013-03-10 | rolando   |
|       2 | 2013-03-10 | pamela    |
|       3 | 2013-03-10 | dominique |
|       4 | 2013-03-10 | diamond   |
+---------+------------+-----------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Let run it again without the first line

```
mysql> SET @DaysBack = @DaysBack + 1; SET @GivenDate = DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL @DaysBack DAY);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO `sold` VALUES ( 1, DATE(@GivenDate), 'rolando');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO `sold` VALUES ( 2, DATE(@GivenDate), 'pamela');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO `sold` VALUES ( 3, DATE(@GivenDate), 'dominique');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO `sold` VALUES ( 4, DATE(@GivenDate), 'diamond');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM sold;
+---------+------------+-----------+
| part_ID | date       | name      |
+---------+------------+-----------+
|       1 | 2013-03-10 | rolando   |
|       2 | 2013-03-10 | pamela    |
|       3 | 2013-03-10 | dominique |
|       4 | 2013-03-10 | diamond   |
|       1 | 2013-03-09 | rolando   |
|       2 | 2013-03-09 | pamela    |
|       3 | 2013-03-09 | dominique |
|       4 | 2013-03-09 | diamond   |
+---------+------------+-----------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

and again

```
mysql> SET @DaysBack = @DaysBack + 1; SET @GivenDate = DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL @DaysBack DAY);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO `sold` VALUES ( 1, DATE(@GivenDate), 'rolando');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO `sold` VALUES ( 2, DATE(@GivenDate), 'pamela');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO `sold` VALUES ( 3, DATE(@GivenDate), 'dominique');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO `sold` VALUES ( 4, DATE(@GivenDate), 'diamond');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM sold;
+---------+------------+-----------+
| part_ID | date       | name      |
+---------+------------+-----------+
|       1 | 2013-03-10 | rolando   |
|       2 | 2013-03-10 | pamela    |
|       3 | 2013-03-10 | dominique |
|       4 | 2013-03-10 | diamond   |
|       1 | 2013-03-09 | rolando   |
|       2 | 2013-03-09 | pamela    |
|       3 | 2013-03-09 | dominique |
|       4 | 2013-03-09 | diamond   |
|       1 | 2013-03-08 | rolando   |
|       2 | 2013-03-08 | pamela    |
|       3 | 2013-03-08 | dominique |
|       4 | 2013-03-08 | diamond   |
+---------+------------+-----------+
12 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

and again

```
mysql> SET @DaysBack = @DaysBack + 1; SET @GivenDate = DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL @DaysBack DAY);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO `sold` VALUES ( 1, DATE(@GivenDate), 'rolando');
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'gummybears' in 'field list'
mysql> INSERT INTO `sold` VALUES ( 2, DATE(@GivenDate), 'pamela');
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'gummybears' in 'field list'
mysql> INSERT INTO `sold` VALUES ( 3, DATE(@GivenDate), 'dominique');
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'gummybears' in 'field list'
mysql> INSERT INTO `sold` VALUES ( 4, DATE(@GivenDate), 'diamond');
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'gummybears' in 'field list'
mysql> SELECT * FROM sold;
+---------+------------+-----------+
| part_ID | date       | name      |
+---------+------------+-----------+
|       1 | 2013-03-10 | rolando   |
|       2 | 2013-03-10 | pamela    |
|       3 | 2013-03-10 | dominique |
|       4 | 2013-03-10 | diamond   |
|       1 | 2013-03-09 | rolando   |
|       2 | 2013-03-09 | pamela    |
|       3 | 2013-03-09 | dominique |
|       4 | 2013-03-09 | diamond   |
|       1 | 2013-03-08 | rolando   |
|       2 | 2013-03-08 | pamela    |
|       3 | 2013-03-08 | dominique |
|       4 | 2013-03-08 | diamond   |
+---------+------------+-----------+
12 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

**AH HA !!!** The trigger stopped the INSERT cold in its tracks where a part_ID had three rows in the `sold` table. MySQL Triggers are not the greatest. Notice I had to SELECT the count of a column that does not exist in `information_schema.schemata` to cause the trigger to abort.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How would you do it in SQL?

Comment: @Sam: SQL is just a language. The above example *is* SQL (albeit MySQL's dialect). In any other DBMS this would be as simple as adding a `CHECK` constraint

Comment: @Sam:  If you want to do it declaratively, move to a different RDBMS.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it and for a very basic reason at least with your current constraint request.

> This table represent parts sold each day, constraint says number of sales should be at least 25 and at most 100.

You may find some of the answers here (on dbs other than MySQL) to be helpful: [Modelling constraints on subset aggregates?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/23475/modelling-constraints-on-subset-aggregates)

However they can't get you there because your constraints have a floor over a period of time.  So you sell 10 of an item in a day.  At the end of the day what are you going to do, retroactively roll those transactions back and then recheck?  What after that?  Go to the customers and demand that they return the products?  So the solutions *cannot work when you have a floor that an individual transaction is not required to meet.*  Your floor has unmanageable failure conditions, and so you can't expect to enforce it.

You could move to a db more like PostgreSQL or SQL Server and drop the floor condition.

Comment: Even if he dropped the floor condition, can he have his constraint enforced __declaratively__ with those engines that you mention ?

Comment: @ErwinSmout, yes there are a few ways of doing this but they require some db-specific assumptions.  See the answers in the linked question.  Note the linked question was, essentially "how can I model a constraint such that for any given transaction, sum(amount) = 0 group by gl_id."  This case is easier (with the dropped floor condition) because you just have to check that the running sum is less than a certain amount.  Note that the SQL Server solutions require additional constraints to work on PostgreSQL.

Comment: Also note that the declarative constraints are complicated, requiring self-joins, some duplication of data, and storage of running-totals, or they require fun tricks breaking 1NF.

Comment: Chris, The accepted answer in that post does not give a declarative solution, and the answer by AKuznetzov forces three extra columns upon the user, and I'm not sure it is entirely impossible for the user to have the integrity test fail because of mistakes in those extra three columns.

Comment: the non-declarative solution is cleaner.  And the other solutions require, on PostgreSQL at least, some extra constriants to make work but with appropriate unique constraints, foreign keys, self joins, etc, you can ensure running totals can be accurate.  This being said, I am not sure it is a net win.  The larger issue though is that this is an area which is unnecessarily painful on RDBMS's even when RDBMS's should be capable of more graceful solutions, IMO.

Comment: Hint:  Think of the subset as a linked list with check constraints and foreign keys to the previous versions (including the running total), and check constraints to ensure the current calculation is correct.  I do think the trigger is cleaner.  It *is* possible, however annoying it is though.