# How to view tuples changed in a PostgreSQL transaction?

Tags: postgresql, transaction

```
BEGIN;

   INSERT INTO foo_table(foo_column) VALUES('a'),('b'),('c');

   -- SELECT * FROM pg_stat_activity WHERE ...
   -- shows records with a flag if they have been added/deleted/updated

END;
```

Is there a way to view the uncommitted inserts/deletes of a transaction for a given table in PostgreSQL 9.x? This is purely for visual confirmation.

While my initial thought is no (just perform a SQL-Select of the table), certain users wanted to visualize differences within the transaction.  I could see how this might be helpful if having a lot of savepoints and transactions. Thus, it was worth asking to the community at large.

Comment: Just select from the table you just inserted into from within the same transaction.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name yes, that's what I suggested, but they wanted to be able to see the records that had not changed, unless you know of a way to show both the original table and include some sort of modified field.  I don't know how else to accomplish this without the use of a temporary table / log, but thought postgresql writer might have something I'm not aware of (possibly using OIDs), since it must be able to rollback a transaction.  I was hopeful when I thought Postgres might track simple insert/update, but I doubt it would be as easy to track updates.

Comment: Sounds like a job for an audit table.

Comment: You want to capture your changed data ?

Comment: @Innnh yes within a transaction, but would also like to show non-affected rows.  Using what Erwin gave, it looks like I can yield the results with a union or CASE statement.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can inspect the system column [`xmin`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/storage-page-layout.html) to identify newly inserted row versions. That includes new row versions written by  `UPDATE`. Deleted rows that were deleted in the same transaction are always invisible either way, so not included in the result.

#### Postgres 13 or newer

The function [**`pg_current_xact_id`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-info.html#FUNCTIONS-PG-SNAPSHOT) returns the current transaction ID as **`xid8`**, a dedicated 8-byte data type representing unique transaction IDs.

For storage and historical reasons, `xmin` in the tuple header only stores `xid`, a 4-byte data type sliced down from the full transaction ID that wraps around every ~ 4 billion transactions. (There is a whole machinery in place to avoid actual wraparounds in the DB.) [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-oid.html)

> Unlike `xid` values, `xid8` values increase strictly monotonically and cannot be reused in the lifetime of a database cluster.

There is also [**`pg_current_xact_id_if_assigned()`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-info.html#FUNCTIONS-PG-SNAPSHOT), which does not burn a transaction ID if non has been assigned, yet (if the transaction has been read-only so far). That's better for the purpose, as there cannot be any rows from a read-only transaction anyway.

Either way, to make it work, we have to add an explicit cast:

```
SELECT * FROM foo_table
WHERE  xmin = pg_current_xact_id_if_assigned()::xid;
```

Here is the thread discussing the patch to add `xid8`:

- https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/2B1364F4-8522-4357-9051-19118B852DA4%40enterprisedb.com#2af551897dc5084068582e4516f510b4

#### Older versions

There is the similar function [**`txid_current()`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-info.html#FUNCTIONS-TXID-SNAPSHOT), which returns **`bigint`**. It is deprecated now, but still supported as of pg 16. It builds on `xid`, but [quoting the manual for pg 12:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-info.html#FUNCTIONS-TXID-SNAPSHOT)

> ... extended with an "epoch" counter so it will not wrap around during the life of an installation.

There is a thread on pgsql-hackers with Tom Lane discussing it:

- https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/28621.1321226208@sss.pgh.pa.us

I derived the safe `WHERE` condition from it:

```
SELECT * FROM foo_table
WHERE  xmin = (txid_current() % (2^32)::bigint)::text::xid;
```

#### Disclaimer

**However**, this does not work with subtransactions started with [**`SAVEPOINT`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-savepoint.html) (or some other way, [plpython can use subtransactions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpython-subtransaction.html), too). Those spawn separate xids and there is currently (as of pg 12) no way to get the full list of xids belonging to the top transaction returned by `txid_current()`. In my search for a solution I found this closely related thread on pgsql-hackers:

- [Re: rows modified in current transaction](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/201208301809.43720.andres@2ndquadrant.com#201208301809.43720.andres@2ndquadrant.com)

I don't currently see a reliable solution working around that limitation.

Related:

- [Can I select data inserted in the same uncommited transaction?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/98576/can-i-select-data-inserted-in-the-same-uncommited-transaction/98580#98580)

Comment: I know two things: 1) I trust Tom Lane 2) I envy your Postgres prowess - this worked beautifully.  I'm curious how deleted rows would be treated, but fortunately, I don't have to worry about them :)

Comment: @vol7ron: Rows deleted in the same transaction are always invisible either way, so not included in the result. But there is a limitation: does not work with subtransactions. Consider the update.

Comment: Yeah, I imagine there might be a number of edge cases.  I don't think it's a common procedures, but I think it's interesting that kind of data isn't available this day in age (knowing there's a lot of other outstanding updates that may have higher priorities).  I'm thinking for debugging purposes, it would be a nice feature; or at least just to cease paranoia for ACID-compliance.