# How to compare xmin and txid_current() after transactions ID wraparound?

Tags: postgresql, transaction, postgresql-9.5

Besides its regular columns, Postgres tables also have various [system columns](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-system-columns.html) available. One of them, `xmin`, stores the transaction ID used to create a row. Its data type is `xid`, a four byte integer that wraps around at some point (i.e. not necessarily unique). The function `txid_current()` in turn returns the current transaction ID, but as `bigint`, because it "is extended with an "epoch" counter so it will not wrap around during the life of an installation" (to quote the [manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-info.html#FUNCTIONS-TXID-SNAPSHOT)).

If transactions wraparound did not yet happen, both values seem to match:

```
# CREATE TABLE test (label text);
CREATE TABLE
# INSERT INTO test VALUES ('test') RETURNING txid_current();
 txid_current 
--------------
   674500
(1 row)
INSERT 0 1
# SELECT xmin FROM test;
  xmin  
--------
 674500
(1 row)
```

But I wonder: are these two values always comparable? As far as I understand, `txid_current()` will continue to deliver unique values after transaction ID wraparound (at most 2^32 transactions) and `xmin` will start from zero. This means both start to return different values at that point?

And if this is true, is there a way to extract regular `xid` of a `txid_current()` result so that it would match `xmin` entries in a table (e.g. casting `txid_current()` to integer)?

**Edit**: Make it clearer that I care about what happens after a transaction ID wraparound, which very likely happens long before 2^32 transactions. Thanks to Daniel Vérité for noting this in the comments.

Comment: You're ignoring the fact that the system will `VACUUM FREEZE` and overwrite the `xmin` on rows long before the 2^32 wraparound. Check out [Freezing Your Tuples Off](http://www.databasesoup.com/2012/09/freezing-your-tuples-off-part-1.html) for an overview on the subject.

Comment: True, I left this fact out of the question, thanks for pointing to it. And indeed freezing will happen long before 2^32. However, even with old `xmin` becoming frozen the question still stands how newer (regular) `xmin` compare to a then executed `txid_current()`.

Comment: It is worth noting that PostgreSQL will shut down if there are less than [1 milion transactions left until wraparound](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/routine-vacuuming.html).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can strip the added epoch to match the value in `xmin`, i.e. extract the 4-byte `integer` from the `bigint`. Since `xmin` is type `xid` and not (signed!) `integer`, we compare the `text` representation instead:

```
SELECT * FROM test
WHERE  xmin::text = (txid_current() % (2^32)::bigint)::text;
```

Detailed explanation:

- [How to view tuples changed in a PostgreSQL transaction?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/123145/how-to-view-tuples-changed-in-a-postgresql-transaction/123183#123183)