# Is it possible to have xid before and after wrap around with the same timestamp?

Tags: postgresql, mvcc

I want to create sync API in which users can get the changes since their last sync request, the API exposes cursor-based pagination (sync token)
A possible cursor may be to use `updatedAt` column along with `xmin` column (I need the `xmin` because many rows may have the same timestamp).

My only concern is if it's possible to have rows with same (updatedAt) timestamp and wrapped around `xmin`:

```
+---------------------+------------+
| timestamp           | xmin       |
+---------------------+------------+
| 2011-01-01 00:00:00 | 4556455456 | -> first row
+---------------------+------------+
| 2011-01-01 00:00:00 | 6          | -> second row, wrapped around xid
+---------------------+------------+
```

Within a specific timestamp (moment), I can be sure `xmin` will behave like a simple sequence, right?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `updatedAt` stores the **transaction timestamp** as reported by `now()` or `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`. See:

- [Difference between now() and current_timestamp](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/63548/difference-between-now-and-current-timestamp/63549#63549)

Then yes, `xmin` behaves like a simple sequence, *basically*.

**But** you may want to look at **`cmin`** additionally. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-system-columns.html)

> The command identifier (starting at zero) within the inserting transaction.

Related:

- [How did this statement update 3 rows in Postgres?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/148858/how-did-this-statement-update-3-rows-in-postgres/148867#148867)

And, **subtransactions** (incurring a [**`SAVEPOINT`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-savepoint.html)) may very well interfere with your plans, as those advance the transaction ID (and hence the `xmin` of rows written after that) *within* the same transaction, while the transaction timestamp stays the same.

So, that's a **YES** to the question in the title. It is possible to have xid before and after wrap around with the same timestamp.

There are various ways subtransactions may get involved:

- Calling the SQL commands manually, obviously
- A PL/pgSQL block with an `EXCEPTION` clause
- The `ON_ERROR_ROLLBACK` setting in Postgres
- Some replication solutions involve savepoints (I think)

Related:

- [How to view tuples changed in a PostgreSQL transaction?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/123145/how-to-view-tuples-changed-in-a-postgresql-transaction/123183#123183)
- [Related discussion on ppgsql-general](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/CAKoxK%2B5Wm6RazPnU8AqB97XRqx5zbY7us00QSVrQgobbgmf8hQ%40mail.gmail.com#CAKoxK+5Wm6RazPnU8AqB97XRqx5zbY7us00QSVrQgobbgmf8hQ@mail.gmail.com)

Comment: Thanks. just to be sure, so I can't use xmin for sync, right? another solution I think about is to save the txid_current value (on every row) which doesn't suffer the wraparound problem and its value only grows. it also should solve the subtransactions problem, am I correct?

Comment: about `cmin` what if two transactions start within the same timestamp? I'll have 2 rows with the same timestamp and both `cmin=0`, isn't?