# What column type can store txid_current value?

Tags: postgresql

AFAIK `txid_current` returns `uint 64` value ([source](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/master/src/include/access/transam.h#L63)).
However, the biggest `int` column type is `bigint` which is signed ([docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-NUMERIC-TABLE)).
From what I understand, `NUMERIC` type is slow and should be used "for storing monetary amounts and other quantities where exactness is required" ([docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-NUMERIC-DECIMAL)).

Should I store the `txid_current` value as `text`?

I need to perform mainly `greater than` queries on this field:

```
select * from t where fxid > 438298432
```

What would be the most efficient (from search speed POV) for full-transaction-id (unsigned integer 64)?

Comment: You could use a bigint and store it with an offset. If you transform your search parameters it should be possible to utilize indexes. Just a thought

Comment: offset = save the first 32 bits in one column and the other 32 bits in another column?

Comment: No, I was thinking in terms of storing 0 as - (2^32) or whatever number that may be. Searching for a specific transaktion would be: SELECT... FROM T WHERE txid =? - n, where n is the offset

Comment: Oh I see, nice idea!

Answer (score 1):

I'm suspicious about your motivations, but I'd say you should either use bigint (which is the data type xid_current returns) or use xid (which is the internal data type for xid's). By way of example, see the following:

```
pagila=# create table xidvals as select * from txid_current();
SELECT 1
pagila=# \d xidvals
                 Table "public.xidvals"
    Column    |  Type  | Collation | Nullable | Default
--------------+--------+-----------+----------+---------
 txid_current | bigint |           |          |

pagila=# select xmin,xmax,txid_current from xidvals;
  xmin  | xmax | txid_current
--------+------+--------------
 358165 |    0 |       358165
(1 row)

pagila=# select attname, atttypid::regtype from pg_attribute where attrelid = 'xidvals'::regclass and attname in ('xmax','xmin','txid_current');
   attname    | atttypid
--------------+----------
 xmax         | xid
 xmin         | xid
 txid_current | bigint
(3 rows)
```

Comment: Thanks, my motivation is: https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/269482/208871, also how it's possible that txid_current is `bigint` and the value itself in postgres code is `uint64`?

Answer (score 1):

On pg v10, The `txid` value is limted to `0x7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF` (`9223372036854775807`) which is fit in `bigint`.
[source code (v10)](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/REL_10_STABLE/src/backend/utils/adt/txid.c#L39)