# XID wraparound metrics are unclear

Tags: postgresql, transaction, vacuum

Recently, I had an issue with one of my database which got XID wraparound issue. So, I have started with `single-user` mode and ran `vacuum`. Everything was fine. But, when I checked `datfrozenxid` its ~1.5billon where as my `txid_current` is ~70billon. I feel like, its huge different and something is wrong.

The below query, I have used to see the `datfrozenxid` from `pg_database`

```
select datname, datfrozenxid, age(datfrozenxid) from pg_database order by datname;
```

I have read a XID wraparound scenario from http://www.rummandba.com/2014/02/understanding-xid-wrap-around.html

It make sense to me as per the Example given in above link. But, I have calculated `xidWrapLimit`, `xidStopLimit`, `xidWarnLimit`, `xidVacLimit` with my statistics.

```
xidWrapLimit = oldest_datfrozenxid + (MaxTransactionId >> 1);
xidStopLimit = xidWrapLimit - 1000000;
xidWarnLimit = xidStopLimit - 10000000;
(I haven't given all the values here since I am looking only for xidWarnLimit)
```

So, the `xidWarnLimit` is 3.747 billon where my current `txid_current`>70 billion. And strange thing is `txid_current` is greater than `xidWrapLimit` which is 3.758 billon.

How to find out, when it will raise the Warning about wraparound warn limit.

(using Pg9.5)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> So, the xidWarnLimit is 3.747 billon where my current txid_current>70 billion. And strange thing is txid_current is greater than xidWrapLimit which is 3.758 billon.

You are presumably looking at the raw return of `txid_current()`, which is not a 32-bit value like the XID Limits you are looking at. Instead, it is

> a 64-bit format that is extended with an "epoch" counter so it will not wrap around during the life of an installation.

([ref](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-info.html#FUNCTIONS-TXID-SNAPSHOT)). You can coax a 32-bit value out of `txid_current()` which you can compare against your `xidWrapLimit`, `xidStopLimit`, etc. like this:

```
SELECT txid_current() % (2^32)::bigint;
```

H/T to Erwin for [this tip](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/148966/31936). Remember that these XID values wrap around at 2^32.

For what it's worth, I think that blog post you linked to is excessively complicating this topic. To watch out for XID wraparound, you really just need to check:

```
SELECT max(age(datfrozenxid)) FROM pg_database;
```

and raise an alarm if that max. age is over 1 Billion or so. And if it gets close to 2 Billion you are in imminent danger! You can use a tool like [check_postgres.pl](https://bucardo.org/check_postgres/check_postgres.pl.html#txn_wraparound) which will handle this check for you with some configurable thresholds.

Comment: can't I store rows more than 2^32 ? If I have more rows than 2^32, what would be the solution?

Comment: Yes, you can definitely store more than 2^32 rows. Postgres used to have a page summarizing limits which is gone now, but see the summary in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21866431/1772673). Multiple rows will simply have the same XID if inserted in the same transaction. And if you tried to insert one row in each of 2^32 transactions, autovacuum would kick in and clean up XIDs for you.

Comment: If I inserted one row in each of 2^32 and all are live, what would be the situation once it reached?

Comment: Read about `FrozenTransactionId` at https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/routine-vacuuming.html , I think that's what you're wondering about.