# Select rows changed in current transaction

Tags: sql-server, transaction

We have table name and `CURRENT_TRANSACTION_ID()`.

How can we `SELECT` all rows `INSERTed/UPDATEd` in current transaction in `MS SQL Server`?

---

**For example,**

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
  EXEC some_big_procedure();
  --How to know what has been done inside some_big_procedure()?
ROLLBACK;
```

Note: original purpose is to test functions by comparing changes made by them with expected changes.

---

**`PostgreSQL`** has such mechanism (see [this question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/146315/154216)):

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
  SELECT some_big_procedure();

  SELECT 'Changed row', t.*
  FROM my_table t
  WHERE t.xmin::text = (txid_current() % (2^32)::bigint)::text;
ROLLBACK;
```

Here `txid_current()` is analogue of `CURRENT_TRANSACTION_ID()`, `t.xmin` is built-in system column contains id of transaction which handles this row.

---

**Bad solution** is to write service function which will go through all the tables and add `t.xmin`'s analogue. This column must be handled by triggers which are created dynamically by that service function too.

Any better idea for MS SQL?

Answer (score 1):

You could return the rows from the proc via the [`OUTPUT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) clause.

```
insert into YourTable(Column1, Column2, Column3)
output inserted.Column1, inserted.Column2, inserted.Column3
--select... or values()... or what ever insert method
```

You would use the same methodology for `DELETE` and `UPDATE`. You can also store the `OUTPUT` into a table for further processing if need be.

[Here is a DB Fiddle showing the below code](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=382fc80b0264fa0ac5e2bbbc0256edb8)

```
create table myTable (i int)
go

create proc myInsert
as
begin
   insert into myTable (i)
   output inserted.i
   values
   (1),(2),(3)
end
go

exec myInsert
go

create proc myDelete
as
begin

   create table #myTemp (i int)

   delete from myTable
   output deleted.* into #myTemp
   where i >= 2

   select * from #myTemp
end
go

exec myDelete
go
```

Comment: In this case we need to modify `some_big_procedure()`. And what if we need to test output from 100 big procedures? Sorry, solution from question will be faster to implement.

Comment: Yes it will be fast to implement. This is almost the only way to do it