# Understanding postgres txid_current and pg_locks

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to get a list of `pg_locks` relevant to the current transaction

eg

```
> BEGIN;
BEGIN
> ALTER TABLE ... ;
ALTER TABLE
> select locktype,virtualxid,transactionid,mode,relation from pg_locks;
  locktype  | virtualxid | transactionid |        mode         | relation
------------+------------+---------------+---------------------+----------
 relation   | [NULL]     |        [NULL] | AccessShareLock     |    11695
 virtualxid | 2/24699    |        [NULL] | ExclusiveLock       |   [NULL]
 relation   | [NULL]     |        [NULL] | AccessExclusiveLock |   801091
(3 rows)
```

Ok so what I think of as "my" lock here is the last one, the `AccessExclusiveLock`

But it has no `transactionid` or `virtualxid`.

If there is other activity in the db I will see other locks too in this list.

How do I filter out just the locks belonging to my current transaction, if they have null transaction ids?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer.

There were two parts to this.

Firstly, what is important is `virtualtransaction` rather than `virtualxid`. Even though `virtualxid` and `transactionid` are null for everything I care about, they all share a `virtualtransaction` id.

Secondly, although `txid_current()` returns a *`transactionid`*, which seems like it wouldn't help because my locks all have null for that, we can still use it to get what we want.

What happens is when you call `txid_current()` postgres assigns a lock with the *`transactionid`* returned by that function, which we can see if we query `pg_locks`. This lock will share a *`virtualtransaction`* id with everything else in the current transaction.

For example:

```
> BEGIN;
BEGIN
> SELECT locktype,transactionid,virtualtransaction,mode FROM pg_locks;
  locktype  | transactionid | virtualtransaction |      mode
------------+---------------+--------------------+-----------------
 relation   |        [NULL] | 3/38672            | AccessShareLock
 virtualxid |        [NULL] | 3/38672            | ExclusiveLock
(2 rows)

> SELECT txid_current();
 txid_current
--------------
       355056
(1 row)

> SELECT locktype,transactionid,virtualtransaction,mode FROM pg_locks;
   locktype    | transactionid | virtualtransaction |      mode
---------------+---------------+--------------------+-----------------
 relation      |        [NULL] | 3/38672            | AccessShareLock
 virtualxid    |        [NULL] | 3/38672            | ExclusiveLock
 transactionid |        355056 | 3/38672            | ExclusiveLock
(3 rows)
```

So now from this we can get the *`virtualtransaction`* id shared by everything in the current transaction, and filter on that.

In other words:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM pg_locks pl
WHERE
    virtualtransaction=(
        SELECT virtualtransaction FROM pg_locks
            WHERE
                transactionid::text = (txid_current() % (2^32)::bigint)::text
                -- compare int to xid, see https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/123183/10371 
                AND locktype='transactionid'
        LIMIT 1
    )
```

...will return only locks relevant to the current transaction.

Comment: also partly answered here https://stackoverflow.com/a/52317996/202168

Comment: Nice! Even though you found the answer on your own should mark it as the correct answer to help others in their search.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
pgb=# begin;
BEGIN
pgb=# select * from pg_locks where pid=pg_backend_pid();
  locktype  | database | relation | page | tuple | virtualxid | transactionid | classid | objid | objsubid | virtualtransaction |  pid   |      mode       | granted | fastp
ath
------------+----------+----------+------+-------+------------+---------------+---------+-------+----------+--------------------+--------+-----------------+---------+------
----
 relation   |    33154 |    12143 |      |       |            |               |         |       |          | 6/20625            | 167525 | AccessShareLock | t       | t
 virtualxid |          |          |      |       | 6/20625    |               |         |       |          | 6/20625            | 167525 | ExclusiveLock   | t       | t
(2 rows)

pgb=# insert into test values(4);
INSERT 0 1
pgb=# select * from pg_locks where pid=pg_backend_pid();
   locktype    | database | relation | page | tuple | virtualxid | transactionid | classid | objid | objsubid | virtualtransaction |  pid   |       mode       | granted | f
astpath
---------------+----------+----------+------+-------+------------+---------------+---------+-------+----------+--------------------+--------+------------------+---------+--
--------
 relation      |    33154 |    33212 |      |       |            |               |         |       |          | 6/20625            | 167525 | RowExclusiveLock | t       | t
 relation      |    33154 |    12143 |      |       |            |               |         |       |          | 6/20625            | 167525 | AccessShareLock  | t       | t
 virtualxid    |          |          |      |       | 6/20625    |               |         |       |          | 6/20625            | 167525 | ExclusiveLock    | t       | t
 transactionid |          |          |      |       |            |        592429 |         |       |          | 6/20625            | 167525 | ExclusiveLock    | t       | f
(4 rows)
```

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps:

```
select l.relation::regclass, l.relation, l.locktype, l.database, l.classid, l.objid, l.objsubid, l.pid, l.mode, l.granted, l.fastpath 
from pg_locks l
where granted = false ;
```

It will display the table name and *where granted = false* shows where access has not been granted (i.e., a lock exists).

Also, you can get your current PID in BASH:

$ ( echo $$; echo $BASHPID )

[get pid in shell (bash)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21063765/get-pid-in-shell-bash)

Some useful queries here for monitoring locks:
[Lock Monitoring](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Lock_Monitoring)